# How to match $_COOKIE[fe_typo_user] with hashed "ses_id" from table "fe_sessions"

Tags: php, hash, typo3

please excuse my bad english.
I am in trouble since we updatet our Typo3 Version.

As a new Security-Feature Typo is hashing the ses_id in the table "fe_sessions" and we can no longer match the value with the $_COOKIE[fe_typo_user] variable.

Do you know a way either to stop hashing the ses_id or to hash the value of  $_COOKIE[fe_typo_user] so that we can match the values again?

Thanks for your help!

Marc

Comment: At which point do you need to "match" anything?

Comment: We have a SQL-Select where we use the matching to get the logged in Frontend User in non-typo-php-apps  
"SELECT username from infoportal.fe_sessions inner join infoportal.fe_users on (ses_userid=uid) ....... where ses_id='$_COOKIE[fe_typo_user]'